# EqualityComparer<T>.Default vs. T.Equals

Tags: c#, .net, generics, comparison, iequalitycomparer

Suppose I've got a generic `MyClass<T>` that needs to compare two objects of type `<T>`. Usually I'd do something like ...

```
void DoSomething(T o1, T o2)
{
  if(o1.Equals(o2))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

Now suppose my `MyClass<T>` has a constructor that supports passing a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>`, similar to [`Dictionary<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx). In that case I'd need to do ...

```
private IEqualityComparer<T> _comparer;
public MyClass() {}
public MyClass(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
  _comparer = comparer;
}
void DoSomething(T o1, T o2)
{
  if((_comparer != null && _comparer.Equals(o1, o2)) || (o1.Equals(o2)))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

To remove this lengthy if statement, it'd be good if I could have `_comparer` default to a 'default comparer' if the regular constructor is used. I searched for something like `typeof(T).GetDefaultComparer()` but wasn't able to find anything like it.

I did find [`EqualityComparer<T>.Default`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx), could I use that? And would then this snippet ...

```
public MyClass()
{
  _comparer = EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
}
void DoSomething(T o1, T o2)
{
  if(_comparer.Equals(o1, o2))
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

... provide the same results as using `o1.Equals(o2)` for all possible cases?

(As a side note, would this mean I'd also need to use any special generic constraint for `<T>`?)

Comment: Note: If `o1` is null, `o1.Equals(o2)` will fail with the ubiquitous `NullReferenceException`, whereas `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(o1, o2)` will happily return false.

Comment: @M.Stramm That's why I said "I'd do something like ...", and not "Here's my production code ..." ;-)

Answer (score 52, accepted):

It should be the same, but it is not guaranteed, because it depends on implementation details of the type `T`.
Explanation:
Without a constraint to `T`, o1.Equals(o2) will call `Object.Equals`, even if `T` implements `IEquatable<T>`.
`EqualityComparer<T>.Default` however, will use `Object.Equals` only, if `T` doesn't implement `IEquatable<T>`. If it *does* implement that interface, it uses `IEquatable<T>.Equals`.
As long as `T`'s implementation of `Object.Equals` just calls `IEquatable<T>.Equals` the result is the same. But in the following example, the result is not the same:

```
public class MyObject : IEquatable<MyObject>
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}

    public override bool Equals(object o)
    {
        var other = o as MyObject;
        return other == null ? false : other.ID == ID;
    }    

    public bool Equals(MyObject o)
    {
        return o.Name == Name;
    } 
}
```

Now, it doesn't make any sense to implement a class like this. But you will have the same problem, if the implementer of `MyObject` simply forgot to override `Object.Equals`.

Conclusion:
Using `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` is a good way to go, because you don't need to support buggy objects!

Comment: Any type with IEquatable.Equals and object.Equals doing different things is already doomed :)

Comment: Thanks. Depending on my use-case, I could even specify a constraint like `public MyClass<T> where T : IEquatable<T>` then. Good stuff, you've all been extremely helpful.

Comment: That return statement looks better like `return other != null && other.ID == ID;`

Comment: If you override Equals, don't forget to override GetHashCode - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23757210/c-sharp-dictionary-file-path-custom-equalitycomparer    [Compiler Warning (level 3) CS0659)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxhbfytk%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Comment: @MarcGravell You cannot avoid it, if you inherit from a class which sealed its `object.Equals` implementation like `DependencyObject`. In those cases it is super important to use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` to make sure your own implementation of `Equals` is called.

Answer (score 4):

By default, until overridden in a class, `Object.Equals(a,b)`/`a.Equals(b)` performs comparison by reference.

What comparer will be returned by `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` depends on `T`. For example, if `T : IEquatable<>` then the appropriate `EqualityComparer<T>` will be created.

Comment: IEquatable<T> rather than IComparable

Answer (score 3):

Yes, I think it would be wise to use the `EqualityComparer<T>.Default`, because it uses the implementation of `IEquatable<T>` if the type `T` implements it, or the override of `Object.Equals` otherwise. You could do it as follows:

```
private IEqualityComparer<T> _comparer;
public IEqualityComparer<T> Comparer
{
    get { return _comparer?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default;}
    set { _comparer=value;}
}
public MyClass(IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{  
    _comparer = comparer;
}
void DoSomething(T o1, T o2)
{  
    if(Comparer.Equals(o1, o2))
    {
     ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use the null coaelescense operator ?? to shorten the if if it really matters

```
  if ((_comparer ?? EqualityComparer<T>.Default).Equals(o1, o2))
  {

  }
```

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Answer (score 2):

That's exactly what `Dictionary<>` and other generic collections in the BCL do if you don't specify a comparer when constructing the object.  The benefit of this is that `EqualityComparer<T>.Default` will return the right comparer for `IEquatable<T>` types, nullable types, and enums.  If T is none of those, it will do a simple Equals comparison like you're old code is doing.