# C# - Dictionary - File Path (Custom EqualityComparer)

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, comparison, string-comparison

**Problem:** Custom Object implements EqualityComparer and IEquatable, but Dictionary doesn't always use these methods.

**Context:** I have created a helper class, `FilePath` for dealing with file paths instead of treating them as strings.  The helper class is responsible for determining if two file paths are equal.  I then need to store FilePaths in a `Dictionary<FilePath, object>`.

**Goal:**

```
  Assert.True(new FilePath(@"c:\temp\file.txt").Equals(
      new FilePath(@"C:\TeMp\FIle.tXt")); 

  var dict = new Dictionary<FilePath, object>
  {
      {new FilePath(@"c:\temp\file.txt"), new object()}
  }

  Assert.True(dict.ContainsKey(new FilePath(@"c:\temp\file.txt"));

  Assert.True(dict.ContainsKey(new FilePath(@"C:\TeMp\FIle.tXt"));
```

I've created my FilePath class:
   public class FilePath : EqualityComparer, IEquatable
    {
        private string _fullPath;

```
    public FilePath (string fullPath)
    {
        _fullPath = Path.GetFullPath(fullPath);
    }

    public override bool Equals(FilePath x, FilePath y)
    {
        if (null == x || null == y)
            return false;

        return (x._fullPath.Equals(y._fullPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(FilePath obj)
    {
        return obj._fullPath.GetHashCode();
    }

    public bool Equals(FilePath other)
    {
        return Equals(this, other);
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(this, obj as FilePathSimple);
    }
}
```

**Question:**

Assert 1 and 2 pass, but Assert 3 fails:

```
 Assert.True(dict.ContainsKey(new FilePath(@"C:\TeMp\FIle.tXt"));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I needed to override GetHashCode() as well:

```
 public override int GetHashCode()
 {
     return _fullPath.ToLower().GetHashCode();
 }
```

References:  [What's the role of GetHashCode in the IEqualityComparer<T> in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095395/whats-the-role-of-gethashcode-in-the-iequalitycomparert-in-net)

[Compiler Warning (level 3) CS0659](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xxhbfytk(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: Although, its good that you managed to find your own solution to your question and post it for others.. I do wonder why you needed to ask it in the first place if your answer and question have almost the same time stamp..

Comment: Turned out to be a [Rubber Duck Question](http://blog.codinghorror.com/rubber-duck-problem-solving/).  By detailing out exactly what the problem was, and experimenting along the way, I reached the solution by the time I was done writing the question.  So I posted it anyway in case it helps someone down the line.