# Generic numeric type

Tags: c#

I have an extension method that accepts a parameter `T`. This parameter is a numeric type, one of the following: byte, short, int and long.

I need to check if `T` equals to 0. How is it possible to do that?

```
public static void WriteFlaggedValue<T>(this OutPacket outPacket, uint flag, T value, ref uint outputFlag) where T : struct,
      IComparable,
      IComparable<T>,
      IConvertible,
      IEquatable<T>,
      IFormattable
    {
        if (value == 0)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: It seems like you'll want [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5182747/2150749) check.

Comment: I dont think there is any built in support to enforce T being numeric, which makes this possibly a bad idea. but couldn't you just do `if(value ==(T)0)`? If you only have 4 possible types, I would probably recommend just making an overload for each of those types.

Comment: How you're supposed to enforce that `T` is `byte, short, int and long`? Generics doesn't seem the correct approach. Maybe overloading suits better

Comment: you could use typeof() and check it for the numeric types.  Then Throw an exception if it is not what you want.

Comment: @tdbeckett while this is true, I still think this approach is rather sloppy compared to 4 overloads. With that method, you end up with a runtime error rather than a compile-time error.

Comment: You might want to look at this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32664/is-there-a-constraint-that-restricts-my-generic-method-to-numeric-types). In particular, Sergey Shandar's and Jeroen Vannevel's answers provide some nice ways to make methods work with any numeric type.

Answer (score 5):

You can use the `EqualityComparer` class like this

```
if(EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(value, default(T))
{
}
```

Stackoverflow: [EqualityComparer<T>.Default vs. T.Equals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5857654/equalitycomparert-default-vs-t-equals)

MSDN: [EqualityComparer.Default](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

One option you have to do this, is using the `compareTo` method of the `IComparable` interface, with the [default type value](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/83fhsxwc.aspx)...

If they are equals it will return zero as [is specified here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fkw3h78a(v=vs.110).aspx).

The condition will look as follows:

```
if (value.CompareTo(default(T)) == 0)
```

Used in your method:

```
public static void WriteFlaggedValue<T>(this OutPacket outPacket, uint flag, T value, ref uint outputFlag) where T : struct,
      IComparable,
      IComparable<T>,
      IConvertible,
      IEquatable<T>,
      IFormattable
    {
        if (value.CompareTo(default(T)) == 0)
        {

        }

    }
```

If value can be `null` then you have to handle it.

Answer (score 1):

Since no one has said it yet, why not simply take advantage of the very straight-forward `Equals(T other)` function that comes for free with the `IEquatable<T>` interface:

```
if (value.Equals(default(T)))
{
    // ...
}
```

---

A note about the use of the `default` keyword in case OP is wondering how this works:

The documentation found [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xwth0h0d.aspx), says the following (emphasis mine):

> The solution is to use the default keyword, which will return null for reference types and ***zero for numeric value types***.

---

It should also be mentioned that just because you are restricting `T` to be a `struct` does not mean that you are guaranteed that `T` will always be numeric.  For instance, your method could accept a `DateTime` as the generic type.  Maybe you already know that and are ok with that.

More on that here: [What is the “base class” for C# numeric value types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828807/what-is-the-base-class-for-c-sharp-numeric-value-types)

Answer (score 0):

How abouts:

```
private T _minimumValue = default(T)

public bool IsEqualsZero(T value) 
{
    return (value.CompareTo(_minimumValue) == 0);
}
```

As suggested in [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6480577/how-to-compare-values-of-generic-types)